# Is it possible to activate and play Mortal Kombat X in Germany?

Tags: steam, region-lock, mortal-kombat-x

I'm wondering if it's possible to activiate and play Mortal Kombat X over Steam, in Germany, even though I would have to get it from another country.

I know it's against Steam's rules to use a VPN or Proxy to activate a game not available in your country.

So you have to use a VPN to activate a (virtual) key, but how does it work if you order the box version of the game from another country and try to activate it then?

May it be possible to do so without breaking Steam's rules?

Comment: See my answer in this thread: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204573/how-can-i-play-dying-light-in-germany/204577#204577

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is now obsolete since Mortal Kombat X and can be bought in Germany without restrictions.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness, can you provide some sort of confirmation for this? All I can find is requests for steam to provide this game, due to it **only just** becoming available. As such, if steam do not provide the game there, this question is still completely valid.

Comment: @Timelord64 http://www.4players.de/4players.php/spielinfonews/Allgemein/35797/2150953/Mortal_Kombat_X-Besser_spaet_als_nie_Pruegler_erhaelt_USK-Siegel_Ab_18.html and see http://i.imgur.com/6li4Ude.jpg. No VPN active.

Answer (score 0):

After asking around in the Mortal Kombat X subreddit, which I knew would have more hope, a user (Denitorious) and [stated](https://www.reddit.com/r/MortalKombatX/comments/32z07f/can_someone_confirm_that_mortal_kombat_x_is/cqg14vk?context=3) the following:

---

> Confirmed. Bought the US version from the PSN Store (US) because it is banned in my country and I can't play with my friend that has the EU (Norway PSN) Version of the game.
>
> I only get matchmade with people from the US now and have input lag every match + many disconnects.

Hope it helps you with your descision.

Comment: PSN is different from Steam. And by now, there is a uncensored German version of the game so the question is now obsolete.