# Mortal Kombat X EU English version?

Tags: ps4, mortal-kombat-x

I have recently brought a copy of this game from ebay with goro as a download. It has not come yet and I was looking forward to it.
I asked the owner a question before which asked if Goro was 100% included. He come back to me saying yes and that I may have to create a us PSN account to download it though.

Upon looking at this I am concerned it might be a US copy and so will lock me into the USA Region when playing online (I am in the UK).

It states on description that this is a EU English version.
Would that be the American version or is it our version? I can not find a meaning for it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too sure what it is you're asking, someone could quite easily mis-sell something on eBay (on purpose or accidentally). I would assume the best and go with it being a European version if that's what he's said in his Ad but there is no way of us knowing. This might be helpful though - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213458/is-it-possible-to-activate-and-play-mortal-kombat-x-in-germany?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean you bought the whole game as a download, or a box with the Goro DLC? If you have a box, you can see if it's from the US or Europe by the youth protection label on the cover. If it's ESRB, the copy is from the US, if it's PEGI, it's from Europe. Either way, if you have an EU version of any game, you would never need a US account for it. If the seller says you need a US account for DLC, then he sold a US copy of the game.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering guys .  I brought a hard copy of the game with goro included as a DLC .  I asked before if goro was included for sure with no reply but then checked a lot of positive feedback and put the order in .   then I got a reply saying I may need a us psn account to download goro!   I said I may want to send it back and he is saying do not worry it is the EU version .

Comment: but I have discovered there is a code at the spine of the case which states which region it is in  ..  The UK/EU one is CUSA 00970  So if it doesn't say that I am not opening the game.

Comment: keep pressing enter for space lol   it is terrible because so many people will not be aware of this until it comes to DLC and some online multiplayer .  thanks answering again